# Is my authentication approach secure / need for improvement?

Tags: security, session, authentication, cookies

on my web app I handle authentication the following way:

1. User enters his email and password
2. Search for user in the db, match bcrypt encrypted password?
3. If so, a new session record gets stored in the db, in it is the user id and a 128bit random key. Also this key gets stored on the client as a "secure", "http only" cookie.
4. Whenever the user makes a request to the web app, the key is the reference for searching the session in the db. If there's a session -> authenticated.
5. Sessions are delete after a certain amount of time (e.g. 3h)

Note: All requests are SSL encrypted.

Do you see any flaws in this authentication procedure? What could be the dangers when working with this?

Thanks!

Elias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two DoS attack scenarios here.

1. A bot can fire random requests with Random session Ids at your server resulting in so many session lookups that your session management can get overwhelmed ideally if your session id can be validated to be a valid session ID using an algorithm before being checked against the DB it would be better.
2. The login screen can be hit by a bot with various uid/pwd combinations which will result in multiple user / pwd searches on the DB.  Having a LRU uid/pwd cache in memory can address this issue and also a captcha for multiple requests from the same IP for logins.

The one point you didnt touch upon is that when will you expire the session - if the user does not log out when will you purge the session id from your tables?  What if the session ID is hijacked from the cookie in the meanwhile?